# OSMDroid offline tiles from raw resource

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using openstreet map for android in my app. And now, i try to create mapview with offline tiles. I read some articles and 'how to' to get to work map with offline tiles from .zip archive.

But one question remainde unclear: can i use offline tiles from `raw` folder at my app project?

Comment: Here is a [demo project dealing with offline tiles](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/OSMDroidOfflineDemo/).

Comment: What is a "raw folder" in your case? And no, you can't use '.osm' or '.pbf' files directly.